# Error installing sqlite3 gem via bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to get the sqlite3-ruby gem (version 1.3.4) installed on my account (CentOS on shared hosting, so I need to install this without root) and the version of sqlite installed is not new enough for more recent versions of sqlite3-ruby, so I need to compile the libraries under my account. The version of sqlite I'm using is 1.7.0 as I found there were issues with the more recent versions.

I've gone ahead and done this already - I downloaded sqlite-3.7.0.tar.gz and installed it as follows:

```
./configure –prefix=$HOME
make && make install
```

Then went to my rails 3 application and ran the following:

```
bundle config build.sqlite3-ruby “--with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib”
```

Then:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

However, I get the following and my bundle fails to fully install:

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... no
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... no
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c sqlite3.c
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c exception.c
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c backup.c
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c database.c
database.c: In function 'initialize':
database.c:47: error: 'SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE' undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c:47: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
database.c:47: error: for each function it appears in.)
database.c:47: error: 'SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c:72: error: 'SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY' undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c: In function 'set_sqlite3_func_result':
database.c:278: error: 'sqlite3_int64' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [database.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas? This used to work, but with more recent versions of sqlite3-ruby it seems like it's a no go anymore.

Here's some additional info:

```
rails -v
Rails 3.0.9

gem -v
1.7.2

.bash_profile:

PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
GEM_PATH=$HOME/gems
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
export USERNAME BASH_ENV PATH GEM_HOME GEM_PATH

which sqlite3
/home/striketh/bin/sqlite3
```

Edit:

I went ahead and changed from sqlite3-ruby to sqlite3 in my Gemfile and ran the following:

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 “--with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME”
```

This error message got me:

```
make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_SQLITE3_INITIALIZE -DHAVE_SQLITE3_BACKUP_INIT -I/home/striketh”/include    -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c sqlite3.c
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:42,
                 from sqlite3.c:1:
./backup.h:7: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'sqlite3_backup'
make: *** [sqlite3.o] Error 1
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: rebuild sqlite3 with homebrew or macports.

Comment: @Codeglot On CentOS? Good luck with that :).

Comment: @Striketh Beside sqlite3 you also gotta have some sqlite3 development libraries installed, unfortunately I don't know exactly which ones. on debian it's libsqlite3-dev and libsqlite3-0.

Comment: The package is already installed on the system, but since the version of sqlite at the OS level is out of date I can't rely on it. I can get gem install sqlite3 to work - I need to figure out if there's an arg I can pass to bundler to modify where gcc is looking for everything, as that's all that's preventing me from installing via bundler

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the solution, which I've verified works.

.bash_profile setup:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
GEM_PATH=$HOME/gems
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
export USERNAME BASH_ENV PATH GEM_HOME GEM_PATH
```

Then run:

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3070701
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make && make install

cd $RAILS_APP_DIR
vi Gemfile
```

Make sure a line similar to this is in the Gemfile: gem 'sqlite3', "1.3.4"

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=$HOME/bin
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Comment: I have the same compile error on my CentOS host with sqlite 3.3.6, rails 3.0.9, gem 1.5.2.  I have root access to the system, and my gems are in /opt, so I'm not sure how to apply your fix.  Can you give me a hint that might help me get this compiled?  Do I need to install sqlite-autoconf?  I'm just using the package from one of my repositories.

Comment: Just for future reference, the gem sqlite3 requires sqlite 3.6.16+. CentOS has v3.3.6 which doesn't work with the gem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the sqlite version requirement. Compiling from source and installing with `gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite-dir=/usr/local` did the trick on CentOS.

Comment: @Thilo I think you meant `--with-sqlite3-dir=` i.e. `gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local`

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then bundle install will work.

Answer (score 6):

Install **"sqlite-devel"** package to build native extensions of "sqlite3" gem on RH-based systems.

On Debian-based systems install **"libsqlite3-dev"** package.

Comment: sqlite-devel is already installed:                                    rpm -qa | grep sqlite-devel
sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5
sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5

Comment: @Striketh You are trying to install 'sqlite3-ruby' or 'sqlite3' gem? 'Sqlite3' is preferable.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. The quotes in my bundle config path were messing things up. I've successfully gotten it installed now.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS, you can use yum (verified works)

```
yum install sqlite sqlite-devel
gem install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

> gem sqlite3 requires sqlite 3.6.16+. CentOS has v3.3.6

So, CentOS user needs to:

```
wget "http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3071000.tar.gz"
```

then, unpack and:

```
cd sqlite-autoconf-3071000
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sqlite-3.7   
make 
make && install
```

then try `gem install sqlite3` AGAIN.