# Fix this error on my Ruby install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, terminal

I'm new to Ruby and trying to get it to run, but when I do I get this message:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed
>   in your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

after I run "bundle install" on the terminal (using a Mac) I get the following:

> Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in
>   `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb  mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

How can I fix this? I've been Googling for a while but haven't been able to figure it out, and I need this to successfully run "rails server" to see my app on the browser =/

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853046/error-installing-sqlite3-gem-via-bundler/6862534#6862534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/Troubleshooting#cantfindheaderfilesforruby):

> **Can't find header files for ruby**
>
> If you get the can't find header files for ruby error message when
>   trying to build an extension or a gem, it means that Ruby cannot
>   locate its header files.
>
> Header files are not delivered by default with Mac OS X, you need to
>   install the Xcode Tools package after the installation. You can find
>   it in the Optional Installs / Xcode Tools directory on the Leopard
>   DVD.

That's it, the system doesn't have the Ruby header files. To install them, you need to install the Xcode Tools package.

Comment: I downloaded xCode from the AppStore and my Leopard DVD is back home (I'm out of the country) is there another way I can install it?

Comment: Let me suggest you something very interesting and cool: [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It may seem like a bit of work at first, but it's well worth it: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: ok, question, if I use that do I still install the Xcode Tools? (sorry I'm a complete Ruby n00b and I'm a bit overwhelmed at the moment ha..)

Comment: I don't think so, I hope rvm will manage everything for you. I can't be certain though, sorry.