# Get undefined method with sprockets 2.0 (can use 2.0.0.beta.15) with Rails 3.1.0.rc5 for Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial sample_app project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, railstutorial.org

Bundle install is green, but when I run "rake" I get the following:

```
rake aborted! undefined method `static_root=' for
#<Sprockets::Environment:0x16b6b78> ... Tasks: TOP => default => spec
=> db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I add "gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.15'"
to Gemfile and rebundle and re-rake. Everything is okay.

Comment: Please run this command again with `--trace` on the end of it. I suspect you're still running an older version of Rails which tries to use the `static_root=` method which is not available in this final release.

Comment: If I go to rails 3.1.0.rc8 and sprockets 2.0.0, but still at sqlite3 and sqlite3-ruby at 1.3.3, I get this: `rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.4), already activated sqlite3-1.3.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)`

Comment: Code demonstrating this question: https://github.com/jasnow/sample_app_3_1

Comment: Fixed my sqlite3 problem with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853046/error-installing-sqlite3-gem-via-bundler

**Successful Rails 3.1.0.rc8 "Rails Tutorial" Gemfile**: http://pastie.org/2457446  

**Successful Results**: http://pastie.org/2457433

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue,I resolved it by

gem install rails -v=3.1.0.rc8

check it out