# Rails (One Month Rails) "Bundle Install" Failure, creating new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I've been scouring the web all day for a solution but can't seem to find a fix for this particular issue; I've seen nearly identical queries but I had no success with those solutions.
 I've just started One Month Rails and every time I try to create a new application like so:

```
Jaimess-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Jaimes$ rails new pinteresting
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
```

That all goes well and once the bundle install finishes I get this labyrinthine error message

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.3
Using tzinfo 1.1.0
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.1
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.1
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.0
Using jbuilder 2.0.7
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using rails 4.1.1
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local
/Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1120:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1119:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:35:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:352:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:165:in `start'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Jaimes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Jaimess-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Jaimes$
```

I've seen a few responses elsewhere on installing sqlite3 but none have worked here, one in particular involving a 'yum' command which goes unrecognized when I plug it in:

```
yum install sqlite-devel
```

After which I only get:

```
-bash: yum: command not found
```

I'm at a complete loss for what I'm doing wrong or what I've overlooked, needing a fresh pair of eyes from a more seasoned ruby programmer!

Comment: try sudo apt-get install sqlite-devel or just apt-get install sqlite-devel.I prefer mysql/pgsql over sqlite3...

Comment: It clearly says `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` which means you need to install the dev tools. Also you are on Mac so you need `brew` to install packages and not `yum`

Comment: I have similar problem, after installing ruby-devel on my system, the error disappears. Your system might be missing other header packages though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to install the dependencies (header files) for the gem

Because the gem is `sqlite3`, I would recommend looking at installing `sqlite` on your system. I think you're using CentOS (?) - if so, you might want to try this:

```
yum install sqlite
```

If this doesn't work, there's a great tutorial here: [Error installing sqlite3 gem via bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853046/error-installing-sqlite3-gem-via-bundler)

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
tar -zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3070701
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make && make install

cd $RAILS_APP_DIR
vi Gemfile
```

Other than that - the best advice is to look on Google for how to install sqlite (not the gem -- the actual files) on your system. This will then allow you to either instal the gem as required or, as is often the case, you'll be able to specify any extra arguments to use